# The document are displayed in a separate layouts instead of displaying in a one layout?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm doing an Android application, when i use the intent, I don't get all documents from the subcollection.

Every collection has a document and a subcollection, so I created a listener on every clicked item, so when the user click the item it should show all the document inside the subcollection, and the code should do the same task, but I don't know why it shows just one document from the subcollection, i searched to see if there are another ways of passing data, but I see that intent is the best.

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new MarketAdapterRecyclerView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {


                CollectionReference path = documentSnapshot.getReference().collection("ShoppingItems");

                path.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                        if (e != null) {
                            return;
                        }

                        for (DocumentChange dc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

                            if (dc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {

                                Item item = dc.getDocument().toObject(Item.class);
                                Intent intent = new Intent (shoppingActivity.this, ItemMarkerActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("keyName", item);
                                startActivity(intent);


                            }

                        }

                    }
                });
```

[Here's the another activity that receives the intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCjSX.png)

[Here's database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k45Oq.png)

[Here's the manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9B32.png)

Comment: Have you set breakpoints or added logging to see if `startActivity()` is being called multiple times or only once? Please edit your question and add your manifest (at least the `<activity>` declaration for `ItemMarkerActivity`) to the question.

Comment: I noticed that the activity is being called multiple times. when i click on the item it retrieves one document instead of 2 documents

Comment: and when click the back button i see another activity with the rest document

Comment: The above code won't provide you proper output. Because When you click on item from Adapter. It starts the foreach loop. Means it will send you to new activity each time it receives new id.

Comment: How should it retrieve multiple documents? You only ever add one "extra" to the `Intent`. You need to revisit your application architecture.